# How to redirect bad/malware traffic to main page without 404

Tags: php, security, redirect, prestashop, http-status-code-301

Im running Prestashop website (moved from bugged Joomla) and have a lot of incomming suspicious/bad/malware attempts to check my page secutity -> Page not found Statistics page. There a lot of Joomla and Wordpress file/catalog attempts.

I have manual redirecter like

```
<?php
    $redir_maps = array(
        '/administrator' => '/',
        '/wp-admin' => '/',
    );

    if(in_array(@$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], array_keys($redir_maps))){
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
        header("Location: ".$redir_maps[@$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']]);
        exit;
    }
?>
```

and it's work very well!
But how to extend it to catch all variables

/index.php?option=com_**??? some kind of regex?** (Joomla Component)
to prevent and redirect this kind of links to /:

/index.php?option=com_jce&task=plugin&plugin=imgmanager&file=imgmanager&method=form&cid=20&6bc427c8a7981f4fe1f5ac65c1246b5f=cf6dd3cf1923c950586d0dd595c8e20b

Comment: If you do this you are telling the crawlers and bots which are doing it that your site is Wordpress, or Joomla, since the links work and do not return errors.  That means they'll just keep trying, or try even more.

Comment: Exactly! Let them come! :) This is soooo stupid to keep trying hack Prestashop with Joomla/Wordpress ways :V

Answer (score 0):

You're not using SEF links? That will hurt your rankings in the search engines. Your current redirect script won't catch all attempts to access your admin page - for example `in_array()` won't match `/administrator/index.php`, since the match must be exact (`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns path, queries, and fragments).

You can get the option query with `JURI::getQuery()`, and then just test to see if it matches a component on your site to allow it. Or do a regex in your `.htaccess` if you're using Apache, it'll use less resources on your system doing it via the web server so the malicious parties aren't draining your resources.

Comment: Nooo i'm using friendly url's. I want to catch that kind of links /index.php?option=com_jce&task=plugin&plugin=imgmanager&file=imgmanager&method=form&cid=20&6bc427c8a7981f4fe1f5ac65c1246b5f=cf6dd3cf1923c950586d0dd595c8e20b and redirect them to main page / . So im looking for solution how to catch only main pattern like /index.php?option=com_ or /index.php?option=mod_ and redirect them from /index.php?option=mod_login?xoxoxox or /index.php?option=mod_rss?yoyoy to /

Comment: That makes it easier - just test the option query key from JURI::getQuery(), and if it's set do the redirect. SEF URLs might have query parameters, but they shouldn't have the option query parameter in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess, before the # ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/.+$ index.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^administrator/.+$ index.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^.+\?.*option=com_.+$ index.php [L,R=301]
```